Obfuscar Obfuscation Error: Unable to Find Assembly After Successful Build in .NET MAUI Project
I'm using Obfuscar to obfuscate a .NET MAUI project. After successfully building the project and running command: Obfuscar.Console.exe obfuscar.xml, I'm encountering an error when trying to obfuscate the assemblies. The Obfuscar configuration file seems correct, and the process begins, but then it throws an error saying it is unable to find the assembly, specifically Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0.
Configuration file:
<Obfuscator>
  <Var name="InPath" value="C:\Path\To\My\Project\obj\Release\net8.0-android" />
  <Var name="OutPath" value="C:\Path\Obfuscated" />
  
  <Module file="$(InPath)\MyProj.dll" />
  
  <Settings>
    <EncryptStrings value="true" />
    <RemoveUnused value="true" />
    <Optimize value="true" />
  </Settings>

  <Rename>
    <RenamePublic value="true" />
    <Skip type="System.Object" />
    <Skip type="System.String" />
    <Skip type="System.Console" />
  </Rename>

  <Output path="$(OutPath)" />
  <Map file="$(OutPath)\Map.xml" />
</Obfuscator>

Error:
Unable to find assembly: C:\Path\To\My\Project\obj\Release\net8.0-android\MyProj.dll
Failed to resolve assembly: 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral'


I tried using the .dll files from both the bin and obj directories, but I still encountered the same error.
I also attempted moving the required .dll files to a separate directory, but it didn’t resolve the issue.
Additionally, I downloaded the necessary NuGet and attempted to run the obfuscation using the exe file, but that didn't help either.

What could be causing this issue? It appears that Obfuscar is unable to locate the necessary Android assemblies despite the build being successful. How can I resolve the Mono.Android assembly issue and proceed with the obfuscation process?
